# How to send back a response from Spring Cloud Gateway without calling the downstream service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to send back the requestHeaders as a reponseBody from Spring Cloud Gateway, but I have to avoid to call the downstream service. I have already accomplished that I can send back the headers as responseBody. But, the problem is that I have to STOP the downstream service call.

How can I achieve this? As I checked the documentation, always call is passing to the downstream services.

Following is my current code:

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, CustomAuthPreFilter customAuthPreFilter) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("rewrite_response_upper", r -> r.path("/request-headers/expose")
                        .filters(f ->
                            f.rewritePath("/access-manager/(?<segment>.*)", "/v1.0/access-manager/$\\{segment}")
                            .modifyResponseBody(Object.class, Object.class, (exchange, s) -> Mono.just(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders())))
                            .uri("http://localhost:9125"))
                .build();
    }
```